# Paste Outlook Table into Excel Worksheet using Interop in c# from background Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, export-to-excel, office-interop, office-automation

How do I 'copy / paste' an instance of an `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table` which has styling (Colors, Borders etc...) into an Excel Worksheet using the Microsoft PIA from a background thread in C#?

It's relatively easily done from the UI thread (STA) using the Clipboard and ActiveSheet Paste method.

Answer (score -1):

You may consider using the Open XML SDK if you deal with open XML files. Read more about that in the [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) article.

Also you may consider using any third-party components designed for the server-side execution.

Be aware, Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2) article.

Comment: Desktop application

Comment: It doesn't matter if you run multiple threads and try to automate Office applications from them.